# select query not working for partitioned table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have partitioned table in my database as follows:

mysql> show create table drugs_info\G;

```
Table: drugs_info
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `drugs_info` (
  `did` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `brand_name` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `generic` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tradename` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `manfactured` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unit` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`did`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 /*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (did) (PARTITION p0 VALUES LE
SS THAN (1000) ENGINE = InnoDB, PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2000) ENGINE = InnoDB, PARTITION
p2 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = InnoD
```

I wrote a select query for `'partition po'` it is displaying wrong result as follows:

```
mysql> select count(*) from drugs_info p0;

count(*) 
----------
64378
```

I am excepting the following result for above select query:

```
count(*)
---------
1000
```

Comment: `from drugs_info p0` simply defines an alias `p0` for `drugs_info`

Comment: p0 is my first partition name in my drugs_info.

Comment: I understand that. But in the way you are using it, `p0` is nothing but an alias.

Comment: then how can i use select query.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is :

```
SELECT count(*) FROM drugs_info PARTITION (p0) ;
```

Also, be careful when using partitions. Sometimes they have a logical meaning like a sales table partitioned by month. In your case, it looks quite arbitrary ; you could decide to completely redesign your partitions six months from now and you'd have to change your code too.

Comment: but it is displaying  ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to y
our MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(p0)' at line 1

Comment: Are you sure that your mysql server supports partitioning ? see [Chapter 18. Partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning.html)

Comment: if i use show variables like '%partition%';
+-------------------+-------+
| Variable_name     | Value |
+-------------------+-------+
| have_partitioning | YES   |